# Windows 7 Mount Software RAID 5 array

Tags: windows, windows-7, raid, raid5

I have a server that died, though the drives appears fine. There are four of them, with a 10GB mirrored volume for the boot, and the rest as a RAID5 array spread across the four drives. When I connect them to my windows 7 box, I can import the foreign drives, and even browse/rebuild the mirrored volume, but it won't seem to touch the RAID5 volume.

Is this a limitation of Windows 7? Do I need to attach them to a box that has Windows Server installed to recover the data?

**Update**: The drives are software RAID managed by windows.

Comment: What type of RAID controller were the drives on? Did you move the controller into your Win7 box and connect the drives to it? I also dont see how you can be doing mirroring and RAID5 with only 4 drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of Windows 7. Only Windows Server versions support RAID-5 volumes.

Comment: Finding a plain-lanaguage reference on this is proving difficult. Here's what I *can* find (search for the phrase "You can create RAID-5 volumes only on computers..."): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786912(WS.10).aspx

Comment: I loaded up a copy of Server 2008 R2 and the volumes worked like magic. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to have the same controller that was managing the RAID5 installed in the Win7 box. From what I can understand by your post, just plugging in RAID5 set to a machine without a RAID controller is going to get you nowhere.

Comment: I think he already mentioned that he tried it from the same Win 7 box to see the RAID 5 but it did not work.

Comment: I kind of thought from the description it was implied this was software RAID... I guess not. I have updated the question.

Comment: Why the downvote, question wasn't even clear.